# Printing prime numbers in Java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, primes

I wrote a similar function in C, and was able to achieve the required result unlike java.
Below is the code, which checks if a number is prime recursively. 
Compilation says, i'm missing a return statement.
The number to be checked if a prime is x. The variable i is the divisor.(ie) x/2, (x/2)-1,...0.

```
public int primes(int x, int i)
{
    if(i==0)
        return 1;
    if(x%i==0)
        return 0;
    else
        primes(x, i-1);
}
```

What is the complexity of this code if I had to print the first 1000 prime numbers.

Comment: For the complexity, at the worst case `i` decreases all the way down to 0, so if `i` begins at `x/2`, it's approximately O(x). But this will amortize to something much smaller since obviously not every number is prime (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). For a mere 1000 primes I doubt it's going to take very long anyway.

Comment: @Ben no it won't amortize to anything smaller because the testing is done in the wrong order. n=1000 primes means ~ **N=8000** numbers to test, by **an O(N^2) algorithm**; don't be so sure that it will run fast  just because n=1000 seems small (you did say "anyway"...) - its complexity is atrocious (see e.g. this [Haskell test entry](http://ideone.com/Y7pnCO) with the equivalent algorithm showing ~ N^2.2 , ~ n^2.5 run-time behaviour.

Comment: I had meant OP's `primes` is O(x) (or O(n) or whatever). So sure, if he loops it's O(n^2), but it's not going to take the absolute worst case because OP has stated he starts `i` at `x/2`, so evens fail immediately. Then to find 1000 primes `x` just needs to be 7919, so primes doesn't recurse very far for most numbers.

Comment: @Ben they did speak about finding first 1000 primes. and I gave you evidence that it *is* worse than N^2.

Comment: the [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) of your algorithm [is ~ n^2.5](http://ideone.com/Y7pnCO), in *n* primes produced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case:

```
else
    primes(x, i-1);
```

You aren't returning anything.  However, the compiler must ensure that something is returned in all cases.  Just return whatever the recursive method call returns:

```
else
    return primes(x, i-1);
```

Also, modify the first case's condition to `i == 1` so it returns `1` on primes correctly.

Comment: Works like a charm. The conversion from C to Java was the culprit!

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it appears that you're missing a return in your else statement:

```
public int primes(int x, int i)
{
    if(i==1)
        return 1;
    if(x%i==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return primes(x, i-1);
}
```

edit: Also, as said in rgettman's answer, there is a logical bug in the first conditional `if(i==0)`. It should be `if(i==1)`. After testing the code with the above edit here is my result:

```
List of primes under 100: 
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `return` inside your `else`.

```
else
    return primes(x, i-1);
```

The `return` there will return the results of the recursive calls, and they'll work their way up the stack. Though, this might lead to `StackOverflowException`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the logic as:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {              
    int counter=0;    
    for (num = i; num>=1; num--) {
        if (i%num==0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 2) {
        //Appended the Prime number to the String
        primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
    }   
}
```

Then display `primeNumbers`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primenumm {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Enter the Number :-");
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
          int limit = s.nextInt();
          for (int i = limit; i >= 1; i--) {
               if (primes(i, i - 1) == 1) {
                    System.out.println(i + " is a prime no");
               } else {
                    System.out.println(i + " is not a prime no");
               }
          }
     }

     private static int primes(int x, int i) {
          if (i == 1) {
               return 1;
          }
          try {
               if (x % i == 0) {
                    return 0;
               } else {
                    return primes(x, i - 1);
               }
          } catch (Exception e) {
               return 1;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class PrintPrime {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
            primes(i, Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i)));

        }
    }

    public static int primes(int x, double i) {
        if (i == 1)
            System.out.println(x);
        if (x % i == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return primes(x, i - 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Primenumm {

static int limit,flag;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter the Number :-");
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    limit=s.nextInt();
    int i=0,j=limit;
    printNum(i,j);
}

private static int  printNum(int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(j==0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(i%j==0){
        return  0;
    }
    else{

        return  printNum(i,j-1);
    }
}
```